# ¿Cómo poner la primera letra en mayuscula en el formato de fecha Android Studio?

Tags: java, android

Ejemplo:

> **viernes - Viernes**

Este es el código:

```
   public String getDate(){
        Date anotherCurDate = new Date();
        SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE, d MMMM 'a las' hh:mm a 'del año' yyyy");
        String fecha = formatter.format(anotherCurDate);
        return fecha;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Hay varios métodos, este es uno usando la función `substring()` :

```
String miFecha = fecha.toUpperCase().charAt(0) + fecha.substring(1,fecha.length());
```

Te sugiero también definir un `Locale` para que siempre se muestre el texto en idioma español:

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE, d MMMM 'a las' hh:mm a 'del año' yyyy", new Locale( "es" , "ES"));
```

por lo tanto, aplicando lo anterior a tu método, este sería el adecuado:

```
public String getDate(){
        Date anotherCurDate = new Date();
        SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE, d MMMM 'a las' hh:mm a 'del año' yyyy", new Locale( "es" , "ES"));
        String fecha = formatter.format(anotherCurDate);
        return fecha.toUpperCase().charAt(0) + fecha.substring(1,fecha.length());
    }
```

Usando el método anterior obtendrías una salida, con la primera letra de la fecha en mayúsculas, ejemplo:

```
Martes, 3 septiembre a las 06:00 PM del año 2019
```